# Increment array value using array[key]++

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, increment

My Java code:

```
        if(wins.containsKey(winner)) {
            int currentCount = wins.get(winner);
            wins.remove(winner);

            wins.put(winner, currentCount + 1);
        } else {
            wins.put(winner, 1);
        }
```

This was my alternative to something I can do in PHP and even C#:

```
if(isset($something[$key])) {
    $something[$key]++;
} else {
    $something[$key] = 1;
}
```

This is going to be used in a high number of iterations in a for loop so I would like to consider performance. Is this whole `remove()` then `puts()` business killing the performance? What is an alternative?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `wins` isn't an **array** (as the title states). With arrays in Java, you can happily use `[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can be replaced to:

```
if(wins.containsKey(winner)) {
    wins.put(winner, wins.get(winner) + 1);
} else {
    wins.put(winner, 1);
}
```

No need to remove the entry. When you add another entry in the map with same key, it will overwrite the existing one.

Comment: It's still performing a containment check, a get, a put and a boxing operation for every iteration. While it's almost certainly not a problem, it's not as fast as it could be.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Hmm. The only real issue is unboxing and boxing. Rest we can't avoid IMO. Not a real performance gain over the original code though.

Comment: You can definitely avoid doing a containment check followed by a `get` (see the second part of my answer) and you can avoid doing a `put` other than for "new" entries (see the first part).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I *strongly* suspect that this isn't going to be a performance bottleneck. As ever, *test* the simplest code that works before you use more complicated code.

You could use `AtomicInteger` instead of `Integer` as the value type of your map. That would allow you to mutate the wrapped value, rather than replacing the whole entry. Then you'd have:

```
if(wins.containsKey(winner)) {
    wins.get(winner).incrementAndGet();
} else {
    wins.put(winner, new AtomicInteger(1));
}
```

If you *can* stick with `Integer`, you could still optimize your code further:

```
Integer previousValue = wins.get(winner);
int newValue = previousValue == null ? 1 : (int) previousValue + 1;
wins.put(winner, newValue);
```

Now there is exactly one `get` and one `put` operation on each iteration.

Comment: Liked the 2nd version. Didn't think of that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this to be as efficient as possible is:

```
Integer val = wins.get(winner);
wins.put(winner,val == null ? 1 : (val + 1));
```

This is very clean to me and avoids the extra hash lookup to "get" the val after you know it's already in there from the contains.